# response.redirect in SPA after logout not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am building my first website. When the user clicks on "logout", I want his cookies to be deleted and to display the mainpage to the user. The cookies aree deleted, but the redirecting is not working and I can't figure out why.

This is my frontend code. I use react and javascript:

```
export default function LoginLogoutButtons() {
...
    function onLogout() {
        dispatch(logout());
        fetch("/api/logout", {
            method: "POST",
        });
    }
    return (
        ...
                    {
                        <img
                            onClick={onLogout}
                            className="iconHeader"
                            src="./icons/logout.png"
                            alt="icon for logout"
                        />
                    }
                ...
   }
```

And this is my backend code. I use express and javascript:

```
app.post("/api/logout", (request, response) => {
    request.session = null;
    response.redirect("/");
});
```

In my network tab I can see some activity regarding the redirecting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNGNd.png)

Where did I make a mistake in my code?

My full code is also on GitHub:
https://github.com/LittleWing85/Wildtiertante

Frontend piece of code: https://github.com/LittleWing85/Wildtiertante/blob/master/client/src/common/loginLogoutRegister/LoginLogoutButtons.js, line 25 and line 48

Backend piece of code: [https://github.com/LittleWing85/Wildtiertante/blob/master/server/server.js](https://stackoverflow.com)
, line 62

I would be very happy if you had a hint for me.

Best,
Alex